# ¿Cómo mostrar productos relacionados en el carrito de la compra?

Tags: php, mysqli

Para mostrar producto relacionado escogía el valor por método GET en este caso el valor es el id del producto.

Obtenía los datos por medio de una consulta, en este caso el **ejemplo** es los colores que posee el producto.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM colors WHERE product_id='$id'";
```

Ahora en el carrito de la compra quiero mostrar una sección que indique también te podrían interesar estos productos.

Supongamos que en la base de datos denominada productos tenga 6 productos.

```
    id | producto
------ | ------
     1 | Cell
     2 | Cell
     3 | Cell
     4 | Cell
     5 | Cell
     6 | Cell
```

Y en el carrito de la compra añado los productos con el **id** `1,3,6`

Cómo muestro en la sección también te podrían interesar estos productos menos los productos ya añadidos a la cesta.

Solo he probado con un producto como el ejemplo ya mencionado.

En este caso como se plantearía o cómo sería la consulta.

> Para mostrar solo los productos no añadidos a la cesta de la compra.

Este es mi carrito de la compra **card.php**

```
 //Carro de la compra

//Si esta definida la ID obtenido por URL
if (isset($_GET['articulo'])) {

    $id_tutorial = $_GET['articulo'];//Obtenemos el ID del producto añadido, para poder acer comprobaciones a mostrar otros resultados.

    //Si esta definido la sesion carro -> es decir si ay algun articulo comprado
    if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])) {

        $arreglo = $_SESSION['carrito'];
        $encontro = false;      

        for ($i=0; $i<count($arreglo); $i++) { 

            if ($arreglo[$i]['Id'] == $_GET['articulo']) {
                $encontro = true;               
            }
        }

        if ($encontro == false) {


            $titulo = "";
            $precio = 0;
            $precioUSD = 0;
            $icon = "";

            $stmt = $c->prepare("SELECT titulo,precio,icon,id_autor FROM products WHERE page=? and status=1");
            $stmt->bind_param("i",$_GET['articulo']);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
                $stmt->bind_result($titulo,$precio,$icon,$id_autor);
                while ($stmt->fetch()) {

                    //Sentencia prepare -> autor proyecto
                    $stmtN = $c->prepare("SELECT autor FROM autor WHERE id_autor=?");           
                    $stmtN->bind_param("i", $id_autor);         
                    $stmtN->execute();          
                    $stmtN->bind_result($autor);            
                    $stmtN->fetch();            
                    $stmtN->close();

                    $datosnuevos = array('Id' => $_GET['articulo'], 'Titulo' => $titulo, 'Precio' => $precio, 'Icon' => $icon, 'Cantidad' => 1 );

                    /*
                        #Si se utiliza array_push() para añadir un solo elemento al array, es mejor utilizar $array[] = ya que de esta forma no existe la sobrecarga de llamar a una función. 
                    */

                    //array_push($arreglo, $datosnuevos); 
                    $arreglo[] = $datosnuevos;
                    $_SESSION['carrito'] = $arreglo;

                    $data = $_SESSION['carrito'];
                    $value_carrito = count($data);
                    $_SESSION['compras'] = $value_carrito;

                } $stmt->close();


            } else {
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }   

    } else { //Caso falso añadimos primer articulo al carro

        $titulo = "";
        $precio = 0;
        $precioUSD = 0;
        $icon = "";

        $stmt = $c->prepare("SELECT titulo,precio,icon,id_autor FROM products WHERE page=? and status=1");
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$_GET['articulo']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            $stmt->bind_result($titulo,$precio,$icon,$id_autor);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {

                //Sentencia prepare -> autor proyecto
                $stmtN = $c->prepare("SELECT autor FROM autor WHERE id_autor=?");           
                $stmtN->bind_param("i", $id_autor);         
                $stmtN->execute();          
                $stmtN->bind_result($autor);            
                $stmtN->fetch();            
                $stmtN->close();

            } $stmt->close();

        } else {
            $stmt->close();
        }       

            $arreglo[] = array('Id' => $_GET['articulo'], 'Titulo' => $titulo, 'Precio' => $precio, 'Icon' => $icon, 'Cantidad' => 1 );

            $_SESSION['carrito'] = $arreglo;

            $data = $_SESSION['carrito'];
            $value_carrito = count($data);
            $_SESSION['compras'] = $value_carrito;

            //echo "<script>window.location.reload();</script>";


    }

}
```

> Actualización detalles adicionales.

La tabla de productos.

```
 id_product       Producto          Marca    subcategoría
-------------  ----------------  ----------    ------
      1          Mini Parlantes       0           1
      2          flash Memory         0           1
```

La tabla de categoría.

```
 id    cat_name   categoría
----  ---------- -----------
 1       HP          0             
 2   accesorios      1             
 3    Samsung        0
```

Estructura:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories (
 id int(100) NOT NULL,
 cat_name text NOT NULL,
 categoria int(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

1. HP

   - Accesorios
2. Samsung

   - Accesorios

El la categoría HP mostramos todos los productos de la marca HP incluyendo los accesorios entre otros.

En la subcategoría accesorios solo mostramos estos productos: flash memory, parlantes, audífonos etc.

> **Nota:** Los accesorios son mostrados a la marca que corresponde.

Ahora sí es un producto que no pertenece a accesorios ejemplo una lapto subcategoría en vez de valor 1 es NULL esté producto solo se mostraría en categoría principal HP.

En el casó de que existiera otra subcategoría denominada lapto este producto se mostraría en aquella subcategoría.

Comment: Mediante **categorías**. En las páginas de compra, las sugerencias se realizan mediante ciertos parámetros, por lo general son categoría y precio.

Comment: @MitsuG En mi casó no tengo muchos productos, por eso quería indicar los productos que estan en la tabla poductos sin pasar los parámetros de categoría y precio pero los dos ejemplos el que indicó y el que me indicas no estaría mal perdón por el atrevimiento.

Comment: ¿cómo es tu tabla productos?

Comment: Sube una imagen del modelo ER de esa tabla para tener mejor idea.

Comment: @MitsuG La verdad amigo no soy muy bueno en crear modelo ER, es más me se confundir.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Propuesta**: En una sección determinada la pagina se requiere listar 5 productos relacionados (de la misma categoría) a los ya añadidos al carro:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])) {

    // Revisamos los productos en el carro
    $idsProductos = array();
    $hashCategorias = array(); // matriz asociativa de Ids de categorias
    foreach($_SESSION['carrito'] as $product) {

        // Si el producto tiene Id
        if ($product['id']) {
            $idsProductos[] = $product['id'];
        }

        // Si el producto tiene Id de categoria y todavia no fue guardado en la matris asoc.
        if ($product['id_categoria'] && !$hashCategorias[$product['id_categoria']]) {
            $hashCategorias[$product['id_producto']] = true;
        }
    }


    if (!empty($idsProductos)) {

        //
        $idsProductos = implode(',', $idsProductos);

        // Buscamos aquellos productos que no esten en el carro
        $query = 'SELECT *
        FROM products
        WHERE id_product NOT IN ('.$idsProductos.')';

        //
        if (!empty($hashCategorias)) {
            // Obtenemos los Ids que estan como claves de la matriz asociativa
            $idsCategories = array_keys($hashCategorias);
            $idsCategories = implode(',', $idsCategories);

            // y que esten en la misma categoria o subCategoria
            $query .= ' AND id_categoria IN (
                SELECT id
                FROM categories
                WHERE id IN ('.$idsCategories.')
                OR id_categoria IN ('.$idsCategories.')
            )';
        }

        // Ordenados por el titule de la A-Z
        $query .= ' ORDER BY titulo ASC';

        // Buscamos los primeros 5
        $query .= ' LIMIT 5';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Ejemplo con declaración prepare()**

Quiero dejar un ejemplo tambien, aunque ya ha sido valorado y aprobado, no veo a nadie contestar en la forma que se a creado la prejunta, ya que no veo en las respuestas la sentencia `prepare()`, para trabajar de manera más segura y enviar nuestros parametros por separado al servidor.

Que problema tenemos para enviar mediante `prepare()`, tenemos que asociar los parametros segun nuestra sentencia creado, en este caso tenemos el problema, que segun la compra tendremos mas parametros o menos parametros, como podemos solucionar esto, os dejo un código funcionado correctamente en mi web :)

Este ejemplo dará una ventaja inicial sobre cómo construir la consulta `SELECT`:

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e26d17/1

Supongamos `$_SESSION['carrito']` contiene los productos que ya han sido comprados por el cliente y `$_SESSION[ 'compras']` mantiene el recuento del número total de productos adquiridos, la consulta `SELECT` para recuperar los productos restantes sería así:

```
<?php

//Si esta definido la sesión carrito compras.
if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])) {              

    //Sentencia.
    $stmt = $c->prepare("SELECT id_tutorial,page,titulo,info FROM
    tutoriales WHERE status = 1 AND page NOT IN (SELECT page FROM 
    tutoriales WHERE page IN (" . rtrim(str_repeat("?,",
    $_SESSION['compras']), ",") . "))");

    //bind_param(?);

    //Inicamos $param como un array, que obtendra los IDs.
    $param = []; 
    //Aqui obtenemso el tipo de variable que vamos a pasar, es deicr, i (integer), s (string), d (double) etc. Para asociar el parametro con nuestro sentencia prepare().
    $paramType = '';

    for($i = 0; $i < $_SESSION['compras']; ++$i){
        //Obtenemos el tipo de parametro para marcadores.
        switch(gettype($_SESSION['carrito'][$i]['Id'])){
            case 'boolean':
            case 'NULL':
            case 'integer':
            $paramType .= 'i';
            break;
            case 'double':
            $paramType .= 'd';
            break;
            case 'string':
            $paramType .= 's';
            break;
            default:
            $paramType .= 'b';              
        }

        //Ligamos nuestros IDs.
        $param[] = &$_SESSION['carrito'][$i]['Id'];
    }
        //Añade los elementos pasados al inicio de array. Observe que la lista de elementos se añade como un todo, por lo que los elementos añadidos permanecen en el mismo orden.
        array_unshift($param, $paramType);
        //Llamar a una llamada de retorno un array de parámetros
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $param); //Ejecutamos bind_param();
        //Ejecutamos la sentencia.
        $stmt->execute();

        //Comprobamos si existen registros en Base datos.
        $stmt->store_result();      
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {

            //Ligamos resultados desde nuestro columnas añadido en la sentencia.
            $stmt->bind_result($id_tutorial,$page,$titulo,$info);
                while ($stmt->fetch()){

                    //Mostramos resultados desde la Base de Datos.
                    echo $titulo; //Etc...      

                } $stmt->close();

        } else {
            $stmt->close();
            //Podrias lanzar un mensaje ya no quedan articulos a comprar.

        }

} else { //Caso falso, no esta definida la sesión carrito.

    //Muestramos todos nuestros resultados desde la Base de Datos.
}               
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberías de considerar el uso de meta tags. Es decir, crear una nueva tabla en donde agregues keywords relacionados al producto en cuestión. Muy similar a cómo lo hacen los blogs o aquí mismo en stackoverflow.

Cuando creas un producto, le asignas estas palabras claves, lo cual te permite identificar otros productos relacionados. El cómo relaciones los productos y los muestres, puedes ajustarlo en base a la popularidad del producto (visitas, ventas) o si este es un producto por el que te pagan para que sea promocionado.

Desconozco tu modelo, pero debes de considerar seriamente el ampliarlo. Entre más información consigas almacenar, más fácil te será llevar a cabo una minería de datos y entregar mejor información a tus usuarios.

Si te quedas exclusivamente con un solo campo (o tabla) en donde un producto solo puede pertenecer a una sola categoría, estas limitando las opciones de los productos que podrías mostrarle al usuario.

Entiendo que tengas pocos productos, pero esto no implica que no puedas ir avanzando en un modelo más complejo y completo desde ya mismo. Esto te beneficiará a corto plazo al entregar mejor información a tus usuarios además de que será más fácil implementarlo ahora que en un futuro cuando tu aplicación-modelo-no productos crezcan.

Analiza cómo se manejan otras compañías que hacen lo mismo. Amazon, Ebay, Mercadolibre, Stackoverflow y es más, revisa cualquier blog. Todos usan tags para identificar sus publicaciones.

Un modelo sencillo sería:

- Productos
- Categorias
- Tags

1 Producto puede tener **1:1** Categorías o **1:N**, dependiendo de que definas por categoría.

Y ese producto debería de tener **N** Tags o Keywords.

Por lo que digamos que tienes este producto:

**Memoria Kingston 64 GB**

En categoría puede tener digamos estas 2:

- Memorias
- Pendrives

Y cómo tags puedes agregarle:

- Kingston
- Pendrive
- Portable
- 64GB
- Memory

Con esto, si alguien selecciona una memoria **USB de 32 GB Sandisk**, puedes mostrarle la de 64 GB, en base a que sabes que la memoria USB de 32, comparte el tag de Memory y Pendrive con la memoria Kingston.

Y así vas construyendo tu modelo y la forma en cómo lo muestras.

Comment: Tienes los Ids de los productos que están en tu carrito no? Bueno, es un Select * from Productos where Id not In (Ids de mi carrito) and Categoria = 1"

Comment: Bueno, pues por lo que veo no entendí tu pregunta y sigo sin entenderla. Tu preguntaste cómo mostrarlos, yo te estoy dando cómo sugerencia una estrategia para el modelo que te permitiría solucionar el problema que tienes, el cómo mostrar tal o cual producto, son las consultas que tienes que hacer. No se que _interesante_ estabas esperando. Porque en base a tu código es dificil determinarlo dado que pones un modelo de algo, pero el código consulta otra cosa. (Autores vs Categorias vs Tutoriales)

Comment: El ejemplo de las bases de datos que he puesto en mi pregunta solo es un ejemplo en realidad es más extensa consta con todos los detalles que me indicaste y un sistema tags incluido amigo :)  ahora si necesitaba un ejemplo a lo de mi pregunta y un segundo ejemplo a lo que me indicaron en el comentario para luego así cuando existieran más productos poder aplicar lo indicado en el comentario para ello necesito sólo un ejemplo sencillo de los parámetros o el planteamiento del código a seguir ya en la adaptación no tendría problemas :)

Comment: He editado la consulta, (*No es mucho la diferencia*). Lo del autor es el autor de la publicación pero esto se descarta... Lo de la categoría lo he mencionado por el primer comentario sería bueno cuando tenga varios productos. Ahora lo determinante es como mostrar en la sesión "***También te podría interesar estos productos***" En aquella sesión mostrar los productos menos los productos ya añadidos al carrito de compra.

Comment: He podido mostrar datos adicionales en el detalle del producto obtenido el id por método GET obteniendo la información por la URLs pero en este caso es diferente... Mostrar los productos menos los productos añadidos al carrito de la compra... aquí se necesita plantear otra forma y ese es el problema que no se que parámetros que planteamiento se necesitará para mostras lo deseado.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías cargar los IDs de los productos que muestras en un string para excluirlos en una segunda consulta con NOT IN.

Por ejemplo:

```
//Productos mostrados
$productos = $db->GetArray("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE autor = '$autor' ");

//Esto crea un strig con los IDs mostrados como esto: '1','3','6'
foreach ($productos as $p){
    $productos_mostrados .= "'$p->id',";
}
//Quita la última coma
$productos_mostrados = rtrim($lista_productos,",");

//Todos los productos relacionados, 
//incluidos los de la primera consulta, 
//menos los mostrados previamente.
$relacionados = $db->GetArray("SELECT * FROM productos 
                WHERE id NOT IN ($productos_mostrados) ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias tambien, simplemente, armar el array de productos relacionados, y al recorrerlo chequear si el ID del producto relacionado ya está dentro de la sesión de carrito, y si ya está "continue"; para que lo saltee dentro del while

```
if( in_array($productoRelacionado->ID, $IDsProductosEnCarrito )) { continue; }
```

Y si necesitas mostrar un numero x de productos, al saltear incrementas la variable contador.

Answer (score 0):

**Propuesta:**

1..  Primera forma  en código MySql, solo agrupas lo que no quiere que se vea y en una sola llamada, ya tienes el filtro deseado

```
SELECT * FROM producto as pro WHERE pro.id!=1 and pro.id!=2 and pro.id!=3 and ...
```

como resultado obtienes **Todos los productos** Excepto las coincidencias del **1 y 2**

Para construir esta estructura para N filtro seria

```
    Productos[] compras=lista; //LISTA de id tomado como parámetro 
    string condiciones="WHERE pro.id!=";
    string cmd="SELECT * FROM Producto as pro ";
    int max=compras.size, cont=0;

    // se arma la cadena
    foreach ( compras as value) { 
       condiciones=condiciones+value.id;

       if(max>(con+1)){ // Verificamos si es la ultima vuelta
          cmd=cmd+condiciones;
          break;
        }else{ // en caso de que existan mas vueltas agregamos mas pro.id!=n
          condiciones=condiciones+" and ";
         }

       cont++;
    }

 ejecutarComandoSQL(cmd);
```

El proceso anterior describe, el proceso de solo formar una cadena,,,, 
para agrupar los productos que **NO** quieres que se vean,
por eso se pone esta expresión, **id!=1**,, combinándola
de esta forma **WHERE pro.id!=1**.

1..Solo obtienes la lista del carrito.

2..Sacas del carrito los productos seccionados.

3..Realizas un filtro en  Mysql de los productos que ya estan en el carrito, mostrando  así , los que no están en el carro.

4.. mostrar los productos restantes, o diferentes ala lista ingresada del carrito.

Answer (score 0):

Esto se me ocurre como una manera rápida de excluir los valores (NO te recomiendo usarlo con demasiados valores de ID ya que esto equivale a una fila de puros OR negados).

```
SELECT * FROM colors WHERE product_id NOT IN (1,3,6)
```

Esto muestra todos los registros menos los que `product_id` sea 1 , 3 o 6

Answer (score 0):

En el siguiente enlace podras descargar un ejemplo de un Carrito de Compras en Php y JavaScript; el script de la base de datos ahi viene adjunto.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8qb1iaenj79r4w/ejemplo_carrito.zip?dl=0

¿Como Crear Ordenes?

```
$total=$_SESSION["cart"]->calcTotal();
$auxOrder = new Orden();
$auxOrder->m_orden_cliente_id = $_SESSION["cliente"]->clien_id;
$auxOrder->m_orden_total = $total;
$auxOrder->orden_session_id =  session_id()."_".time() ;    
$order_id = $auxOrder->guardar();

/*Guardar Productos*/

$auxPrCart = new Producto();    
$auxPrCartA = new Producto();   
$colProducts = $_SESSION["cart"]->colProducts;
$cantProducts = count($colProducts);

if($order_id != ""){

    for ($i=1; $i <= $cantProducts; $i++){
        /*Get Product*/
        $rowProduct = $_SESSION["cart"]->mostrarProduct($i);
        /*Get from database*/
        $rowProdBase= mysql_fetch_object($auxPrCart->darUno($rowProduct->mId));
        /*save into database*/
        $auxPrCartA->mIdOrden =$order_id;
        $auxPrCartA->mId =$rowProduct->mId;
        $auxPrCartA->mQty =$rowProduct->mQty;
        $auxPrCartA->mCost =$rowProduct->mCost;     
        $auxPrCartA->guardarProdOrder();

    }
}
```